# How to Create Unmanaged vhds in Azure ARM

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I´m trying to create such Azure Bicep/ARM script that will deploy new Azure VM with new unmanaged disk, optionaly with custom size (for example 60 Gb).

I have consider many option including (and most promising looking)custom image, but from my understanding I still need existing vhd in storage blob prior deploynment and I can´t find any other way how to create vhd than that I create VM in portal with unmanaged disk and than detaching it, unfortunatelly that is really no option for me because I´m trying to automate whole process...

Thank you in advance for any advice, even simple it cannot be done, will help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you want to create VMs by ARM template via your custom image, You can refer to docs below to capture VM images:

[Capture windows VM image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource)

[Capture Linux VM image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image)

If you want to use managed images to create VMs by ARM template, you can just specify your managed images resource ID in `imageReference`. You can find detailed steps [in this blog](https://pyronoidninja.com/create-a-vm-from-a-managed-image-in-azure/).

You also could [create VMs from the Azure portal or by PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized-managed)